# Binding multiple sources into a single XAML Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have three different data sources, for example:

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Layer"/>
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="New"  />   
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Option"  />
```

And if I wanted all the results to go into a single combo box, how would I bind multiple sources?

I can get single binding to work:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Layer}}" />
```

But I wanted something like this (which doesn't work):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Layer, New, Option}}" />
```

Is there something along the lines similar I could do instead, or am I missing something or wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a `CompositeCollection` should work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Layer" Source="{Binding Layer}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="New" Source="{Binding New}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Option" Source="{Binding Option}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
     <CompositeCollection>
          <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Layer}}" />
          <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource New}}" />
          <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Option}}" />                         
     </CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try MultiBinding?
I saw [this example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/737821a3-83c9-4854-8f65-8ecc155d98d7/how-to-set-multiple-itemssources-to-combobox?forum=wpf) of MultiBinding and its look like what you need.
this is from the example:

```
     <ComboBox Height="30" Width="150" Margin="5" >
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConditionToItemSourceConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsPerson"/>
                <Binding Path="Persons"/>
                <Binding Path="Employees"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
```

And you can always combine the 3 sources to 1 in the code and bind it to the combobox.